# Decoding a .bin file encoded with ANSI format

Tags: python, decode, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am attempting to decode a very large .bin file which contains a header as well as numeric data. The problem I am running into is the method I am using to decode is producing a jumbled list of characters. When opening the file in a text editor it tells me that the encoding is 'ANSI' so that is what I am using for this

I am using this code to decode it:

```
import codecs as cs

file = open('3D_test.bin', 'rb')

b = file.read( ) ##inserting a number here in the actual code

data = cs.decode(b, encoding='ANSI')

print(b)
print(data) ##this one shows me the jumbled characters but I can't seem to show that here
```

The first 100 bytes, which is header data:

```
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\x10@\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00L\x00\x00\x00L\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00 Longitude                              (\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00'
```

Some bytes that are after the header data:

```
b'\xd7\xa4\x97\x07\xa4\x94\x10@\xe9A\xc3h\x00\xee\x10@\xfb\xde\xee\xc9\\G\x11@\r|\x1a+\xb9\xa0\x11@\x1f\x19F\x8c\x15\xfa\x11@1\xb6q\xedqS\x12@CS'
```

I've tried quite a bit of digging but can't seem to find anything that helps me with this problem. I'm not new to python but have never worked with binary data/decoding data before.

Comment: codecs.decode() does not do anything useful, because that is for decoding text, and this isn't text (that "ANSI" bit is probably a red herring; it's just the text editor being confused when confronted with something that isn't text). A .bin file isn't really a well defined concept — there are many file formats which use that extension. Your first step must be to find out exactly what the format of the file is.

Comment: @TurePålsson How would I go about finding out the exact format of the file?

Comment: Presumably this file did not magically appear on your computer, but was provided by someone or produced as output of some program. Asking that someone, or checking the documentation of that program, would be a great start. Failing that, an internet search like "bin file numismatics" (assuming numismatics is the subject you are working with!) might turn up something.